# Is it possible to have distinct scrolling while editing a response?

Tags: feature-request, markdown-preview

When editing a post, you've got a markdown edit area, then some kind of preview packed below. If the post happens to be long - and actually about a few tens of lines make it long - it becomes impossible to see both what you are editing and the rendering, as scrolling the preview does remove the markdown from your sight.

This is I think a feature request: is it possible to have at least the preview scroll on its own? Or better, have it scroll on its own *and* focus at the very point we've just made some modification?

Or is it a problem with my browser? Or did I not search the site with adequate keywords?